# Minifying and inlining tool for less

Tags: less, minify

I am looking for a tool to minify a website to one file.
I found [inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner/) but it also inclue my less client script and I would like my less to by compiled to css and be included.

I want to inline javascript, stylsheet and images.

Is there any tool I could use ?

Comment: Check this out, https://github.com/mcollina/rake-minify

Comment: I didn't specified, but I would prefer a nodejs tool.
I am going to check this anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, I didn't find a perfect tool, and I don't have more time to spent looking for one.

I think what I was looking for was something like [Node-AMS](https://github.com/kof/node-ams) or [grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt).
Node-AMS seems to be very similar to grunt, but grunt have a bigger community.

I might in the future create some of the tools I need as grunt plugins.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search led me to these options:

- [Node-AMS](https://github.com/kof/node-ams) - minify js (using uglifyjs), minify css (using cssmin from yahoo), inline small images in css using base64 data encoding, etc.
- [Bundler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler) - compiles, minifies and combines your websites less, sass, css, coffeescript and js
- [Node-minify](https://github.com/srod/node-minify) -  compress javascript and css files with Yui Compressor / Google Closure Compiler / UglifyJS

Comment: None of these tools seems to inline also images, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Opra](https://github.com/jakobmattsson/opra)

**O**ne **P**age to **R**ule them **A**ll

Provides functions for serving and building html-files for single page applications.

Handles such tedious things as concatenating, compressing and compiling files before putting them into the html file.

Supports coffeescript and less out of the box.