# CSS Class Selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to shorten my css file (total of 4843 lines), I want to apply this file to a single div with a class named "block1" like this:

```
  .block1{

      .pages{
         //some style
      }
   }
```

not like this(kills a lot of time):

```
    .block1 .pages{ //some style }

    .block1 .titles{ //some style }
```

It seems this doesn't work out. is there any other way around which i could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [less](http://lesscss.org). Less does exactly this.

From the less site abstract

> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions.

It is not css, but it compiles to css. It might not shorten your resulting css, but it will make it a lot more manageable.

If you want manageable styles and then also shorten it, you could build your styles using less and then minify the resulting css using something called a minifier. Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353271/minifying-and-inlining-tool-for-less).

Comment: I made some digging around and found it finally! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By using a CSS preprocessor like [Less](http://lesscss.org) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).